# Extract version info from a string

Tags: bash

I want to extract `versionCode` and `versionName` from this string:

```
package: name='com.turastory.mysampleapp' versionCode='11' versionName='1.1.4'
```

I think I should do these actions:

1. find `versionCode` in the string.
2. find ' (single quote) starting from the position we've found in step 1.
3. read characters until another single quote appears.
4. Repeat same process (1~3) with `versionName`

But I don't know how to do it using Bash script. Help me please @_@

Comment: You need to use the substring function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash

Comment: An easy way to accomplish this would be using perl (awk or other similar tools could do this too) and some regular expressions. `VERSION=$(echo $STRING | perl -n -e "if(/versionCode='([0-9.]+)'/){print \$1}")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that string from which you want to extract versionCode and versionName would always be in the format you provided.

```
package: name='com.turastory.mysampleapp' versionCode='11' versionName='1.1.4'
```

Say above string is saved under filename `package_info`, then Using [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) would be simple and much faster :

- Get the `versionCode`

  ```
  cut -d "'" -f 4 package_info
  ```
- Get the `versionName`

  ```
  cut -d "'" -f 6 package_info
  ```
- Combining the two

  ```
  cut -d "'" -f 4,6 package_info
  ```

#### A Brief about cut :

`cut` utility extracts substring based on the `delimiter` (space by default) and `fields/characters`.

- By default Delimiter is a `literal space`, that can be changed using **`-d`**.
- In your case, the delimiter is **`'`**
- **`-f`** tells cut to extract the fields relatively numbered  (here `4` or `6` ) on the basis of delimiter defined.

For some hands-on on cut, [visit here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/) and feel free to add in more details.

Comment: I wrote the script using substring function, but this method seems more appropriate for me. And +1 for that brief introduction about cut.